# Why is CSS3 transform attribute format designed like that?

Tags: css, web, css-transitions, css-transforms

Currently, the CSS3 transform syntax is designed like this:

```
transform: translate(350px, -350px) rotate(360deg);
```

I was just curious why it is not designed separately like this:

```
translate: 350px, -350px;
rotate: 360deg;
```

Or with a prefix for explicity:

```
transform-translate: 350px, -350px;
transform-rotate: 360deg;
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: [A transformation is applied to the coordinate system an element renders in through the transform property. This property contains a list of transform functions. The final transformation value for a coordinate system is obtained by converting each function in the list to its corresponding matrix like defined in Mathematical Description of Transform Functions, then multiplying the matrices.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property). So,  `transform` is a property and the `translate`s and `rotate`s are the functions applied to the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the customizable arguments it resembles other CSS property/value pairs. For example:

```
transform: rotate;
transform: perspective;
transform: scale;
```

appears more like other common property/value pairs. For example:

```
display: block;
display: inline-block;
display: table;
```

The difference being the property values for some `transform`s accept parameters to customize them.

What ***is*** confusing is why multiple transforms don't follow the comma-delimited format other property/value pairs do for multiple values. For example, to apply multiple background images you would do something like:

```
.class {
  background: background1, background 2, ..., backgroundN;
}
```

but `transform` uses a space-delimited format of:

```
transform: transform1() transform2() transform3() ... transformN();
```

The only reason this makes some sense (to me) is the transforms aren't independent of each other - instead, each transform is acting on the previous transform.

Comment: That is because those aren't values. They are functions. Final value is computed by converting each function to its matrix and then multiplying those matrices.